# What does Drupal Commerce have that Magento doesnt? And vice versa

Tags: commerce

Looking for an ecommerce solution and wanted to know how does Magento compare? Does it have things like the View's module? CCK? Panels? Or the popular modules that are widely used in Drupal.

What does Magento have that Drupal doesnt?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. As per [FAQ], questions about comparing Drupal with similar software is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not going to get a better answer than someone whos done an article on it...

http://www.richardcarterconsultancy.com/2012/07/magento-vs-drupal-commerce/

Comment: good write up, but i feel the author hasn't fully tweaked his Drupal installation to really take full potential of it. Would be great to see a vetern drupal dev to give a good analysis of how it compares to Magento. I just dont know how any cms can operate without something like Views.